# JavaScript Weather App using 3 APIs

Tags: javascript, api

This is one of my first programs working with APIs and I was hoping to get some input in the form of suggestions, recommendations or corrections.  The goal is to register the user location by IP, derive a latitude and longitude from the [ip-api](http://ip-api.com) public site, pass this to Open Weather’s API for weather details and description, and use this information to search for a Flickr image of the location.

I have only been working with Javascript for a few months so any suggestions would be very much appreciated.  If you can recommend any sources to remediate any shortcomings that would be appreciated as well.

```js
var displayData = {
  city: document.querySelector("#city"),
  temperature: document.querySelector("#temperature"),
  weather: document.querySelector("#weather"),
  icon: document.querySelector("#icon"),
  source: document.querySelector("#source")
  };

function getWeather(latitude, longitude) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      displayData.city.innerHTML = response.name;
      displayData.temperature.innerHTML = response.main.temp;
      var detailWeather = response.weather[0];
      var description = detailWeather.description;

      flickrLoad(latitude, longitude, description); 

      displayData.weather.innerHTML = description;
      displayData.icon.src = "http://openweathermap.org/img/w/" + detailWeather.icon + ".png";
    }, false);

    xhr.addEventListener("error", function(err){
      alert("Initial request error");
      }, false);

    var target = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&appid=54e7bed8487f1b7de520fa68a9080abe&units=imperial" ;

  xhr.open("GET", target, true);
  xhr.send();
  } else {
    alert("Initial XMLHttpRequest");
  }
}


function flickrLoad(latitude, longitude, description){
    var searchDesc, splitDesc;
    splitDesc = description.split(" ");
    searchDesc = splitDesc.slice(-1)[0];
    console.log(searchDesc);

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
        var response = xhr;
        var fullText = response.responseText;
        var segment = (fullText.slice(14, -14)) + "}";
        var fullJSON = JSON.parse(segment); 
        var imgURL = fullJSON.photos.photo[0].url_l;
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = imgURL;
        body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + imgURL + ')';       

    }, false);
    xhr.open("GET", "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=c004bd46564d26383d37d88c1cbd4154&lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&accuracy=1&tags=" + searchDesc + "&sort=relevance&extras=url_l&format=json", true);
    xhr.send();
}}


function findIP(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        console.log(response.lat, response.lon);
        getWeather(response.lat, response.lon);
        displayData.source.innerHTML = "From: " + response.query;
    }, false);
    xhr.open("GET", "http://ip-api.com/json", true);
    xhr.send();
}}

findIP();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #696969;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#imageSupport {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}


#shell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


#main {
  width: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7)
}

#footer {
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;   
}

a {
  color: #800000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Weather App 25 Sept</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="wx25.css">
</head>
<body >
  <div id="imageSupport">
  <div id="shell">

  <section id="main">
    <h1 id="city">Weather Web App</h1>
    <h4 id="source">Local IP</h4>
    <p id="temperature"></p>
      <span id="weather"> By Cameron</span><br>
      <img id="icon">
 
  </section>
  </div>
  </div>

<footer id="footer">

      <a href="http://flickr.com/services/api/"> Flickr</a> and <a
      href="http://openweathermap.org"> Openweathermap.org</a>

</footer>

<script src="wx25.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

Consider using the newer [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). it's simpler to use. Although [it's not supported in about half the browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch) in the market, [there's a polyfill](https://github.com/github/fetch).

Should you still want to continue down the `XMLHttpRequest` path, consider wrapping the XHR logic in a function for reusability. You're repeating your code significantly on all 3 functions.

Whether it's `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`, consider using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). It allows for better async control than just plain callbacks. `fetch` returns promises by default. For `XMLHttpRequest`, you might want to wrap it in one.

Here's an example of how to wrap xhr with a promise:

```
function promisingXHRGet(url, options){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", function(){
      resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
    }, false);
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```

Here's how the could could have looked like using `fetch` and promises.

```
function getWeather(latitude, longitude) {
  return fetch(...).then(function(response){
    // Convert response object to JSON before passing it along
    return response.json();
  });
}

function getFlickrImage(latitude, longitude, description){
  return fetch(...).then(function(response){
    // Convert response object to JSON before passing it along
    return response.json();
  });
}

function getIP(){
  return fetch(...).then(function(response){
    // Convert response object to JSON before passing it along
    return response.json();
  });
}

function getInfo(){
  return getIP().then(function(data){
    // Do stuff with IP data
    // Retrieve weather data
    return getWeather(...);
  }).then(function(data){
    // Do stuff with weather data
    // Retrieve Flickr image
    return getFlickrImage(...);
  }).then(function(data){
    // Do stuff with flickr data
  });
}

getInfo();
```

The code isn't very different. you still have 3 functions to interface with the API and there's your logic.

However, notice that we've reversed the responsibility. The logic now resides in the caller side of the code, in `getInfo`, instead of in the 3 functions. This allows the 3 functions to be reusable and not be bound to business/UI logic.

Also, with promises, your code now appears linear with the use of `then`. The magic of `then` is that when you return a promise from the callback, the next `then`'s callback will not execute until that resolves. That gives you the feeling that the code is "waiting".

Now onto your HTML and CSS.

One issue that's as clear as day is the use of `id`. First, IDs must be unique on the page. Although nothing will stop you from reusing an ID, there's no guarantee libraries and APIs will work. When you drop your code onto a page, there's no guarantee that it will not collide with other elements. Use classes to be safe.

Another problem with IDs is that it has a very high [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). ID styles can only be overridden by either:

- A style declaration that uses the ID but comes after your styles.
- A style declaration that uses an ID and another attribute.
- An inline style or style set using JavaScript.
- Any selector, but with properties using `!important`.

You don't want your CSS specificity to be very high. Otherwise, you'll be eating up this list up to the last item until you can't style the element anymore.

With both issues, consider using the [BEM](https://en.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/) naming scheme. In a gist, it solves both problems by 1) using classes and 2) classes have very low specificity. This will give you collision-free naming as well as easy overriding of styles.

Comment: thank you very much for taking the time to provide this review.  I had heard of "Promises" but haven't covered them, I will now.  "Fetch" is not something I had heard of...Thank you for the references, I appreciate the help.